# Visual Studio Code path syntax

Tags: visual-studio-code

Documentation at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference is a bit fragmented. Can I use both `path` and `path/**` for recursive search and `path/*` for non-recursive search in `includePath` property?

Answer (score 1):

Form the linked documentation (emphasis mine)

> `path` A list of paths for the Tag Parser to search for headers included by your source files. If omitted, `includePath` will be used as the `path`. ***Searching on these paths is recursive by default***. Specify `*` to indicate non-recursive search. For example: `/usr/include` will search through all subdirectories while `/usr/include/*` will not.

And from the entry on includePath, since it is used if path is omitted (again, emphasis mine)

> `includePath` An include path is a folder that contains header files (such as `#include "myHeaderFile.h"`) that are included in a source file. Specify a list of paths for the IntelliSense engine to use while searching for included header files. ***If a path ends with `/**` the IntelliSense engine will do a recursive search for header files starting from that directory.*** If on Windows with Visual Studio installed, or if a compiler is specified in the `compilerPath` setting, it is not necessary to list the system include paths in this list.

Yes, use either `path` or `path/**`

Comment: I've seen that, but it wasn't clear to me that the same syntax rules apply across different properties.

Comment: @PaulJurczak Could always just try it and see if it works!

Comment: My problem is that none of them work, but this is a subject for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

For recursive search in `includePath` property, `path/**` should be used.

Form the linked documentation (emphasis mine)

> `includePath` An include path is a folder that contains header files
> (such as `#include "myHeaderFile.h"`) that are included in a source
> file. Specify a list of paths for the IntelliSense engine to use while
> searching for included header files. **Searching on these paths is not
> recursive**. Specify `**` to indicate recursive search. For example,
> `${workspaceFolder}/**` will search through all subdirectories while
> `${workspaceFolder}` will not. If on Windows with Visual Studio
> installed, or if a compiler is specified in the `compilerPath` setting,
> it is not necessary to list the system include paths in this list.